# Installing Wordpress inside a directory of Opencart

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, fopen, opencart

What I am trying to do is install WordPress inside a directory of my already existing Opencart installation, for example domain.com/opencart/wordpressblog.

In my Opencart installation I have SEO Url's turned on, so when i access domain.com/opencart/wordpressblog i am taken to a "The page you requested cannot be found!" part of opencart.

If anyone could help me access that directory I would be greatly thankful, or if you know of any better ways to integrate opencart with worpress...

Thanks,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Just add line below to your root .htaccess file ;
(assuming your wordpress is installed foldername is "blog" )

```
RewriteRule blog/ - [L]
```

This will leave apart this folder from rewriting directives